# How to resolve CORS error with GoogleCast sample hosted on Google drive?

Tags: https, cors, chromecast, google-cast

I'm new to Chromecast/Web dev, but I downloaded and loaded the "Cast-Player-Sample" [from github here](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample) to my Google Drive, then published the public URL in my developer account.  I also associated my devices/serials/rebooted. I'm receiving this error in the console:

> The page at 'https://www.googledrive.com/host/[REDACTED]/player.html'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from
>   'ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc': this content should also be loaded over
>   HTTPS.

Everything I read says it's a CORS issue and that Google drive doesn't allow `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` because someone could steal all of your drive-data, which makes sense.

How can I resolve this error?

Screenshot: [image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: That is not CORS issue; the URL you mentioned is related to websocket. Outside of this error, what issues are you running into?

Comment: I attached a screenshot to the original question. The next error is `Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.` I'm not exactly sure what the sample "does".  I see a chromecast icon against a black background with a spinning circle and that's it. How can I `cast` to this? I was imagining it would show up as a receiver in my Chrome's Cast Extension, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error I see in console has a wrong url for your player.html; did you host that correctly on Google drive (see instructions [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)) and when you registered your app? URL should look like https://www.googledrive.com/host/some_doc_id

Comment: I believe I did everything correctly and I just re-did it from scratch. https://ba547803f15d96fdb3b0ec72daaf193c180386c3-www.googledrive.com/host/0B4pepv-NkqXNbEUwMjBjeG94d0k/player.html is the URL I registered in the dev console and access and https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B4pepv-NkqXNbEUwMjBjeG94d0k is the actual directory with files.

Comment: Try registering your receiver as https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B4pepv-NkqXNbEUwMjBjeG94d0k/player.html

Comment: I just changed it to that URL and it still does not work. The odd thing is the "Preview" button in the dev console shows it working.

Comment: reboot your Chromecast so it can pick up the new configuration after making changes on the dev console.

Comment: Same issue. My Chromecasts/Serials are added to the dev console too and I have the checkbox to update set. What do my Chromecasts have to do with this though at this point? I may not understand exactly how a custom receiver functions. I was thinking that I would go to the webpage in Chrome, see the black page and in the upper right corner, the Cast Extension would display a new "receiver" device that I could cast to on my network or something? And then if I cast something like YouTube on my phone to it, it would start playing on my Chrome browser I had open.

Comment: Ok, it seems like you are doing things incorrectly. The receiver (the sample you downloaded from github and hosted on your drive) is a receiver, i.e. it won't load correctly on your desktop chrome but loads on chromecast. You then need a sender; you can grab any of the three reference senders that we have on the github (CastVideos-andoid, ios or chrome) and set the App Id that you obtained through registration on in  sender of your choice and then use the sender app to cast media. Read about the cast paradigm on our documentation site.

Comment: Ah I see. So the "receiver" is really like an overlay template. The AppId corresponds to the published URL of the receiver. Then when I choose to send/cast data to my Chromecast, I create a `SessionRequest` referring to the registered AppId, which causes the Chromecast to display my "receiver" design. Is there anyway to create a web-hosted receiver? My idea was I could cast media to a "virtual receiver", which would also function as a sender and connect to several Chromecasts. So you could use your phone on your network to connect to the "virtual receiver" and play on multiple Chromecasts.

Comment: Also, if I could create a "virtual receiver", I could cast directly to other misc devices instead of limiting what can receive a "cast" to the Chromecast. I was imagining Android tablets behind plexiglass in office buildings, or Windows/Mac display terminals as well.

Comment: I don't know what an "overlay template" is but receiver is basically an html5 application that runs on your chromecast or other cast devices. Each sender can be connected to at most one receiver at a time.

Comment: My sender can connect to multiple Chromecasts. Here is a prototype https://d7d0af8e68c0b6d3590c73f6918f6ced79aa9c94.googledrive.com/host/0B4pepv-NkqXNcm5BUVJXaVM4NTA/CastHelloVideo-chrome-master/index.html . Click "Launch App", then choose one Chromecast, then select "back to device list" and select another Chromecast seen here http://i.imgur.com/E2AV8xq.png . Then click "Load media" and it will play to multiple devices and attempt to sync them.